# Sort xslt output by result of count($Rows)

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt, sharepoint-2007

i want to display Tags by their number of use in a sharepoint list. The order should be descending so that the most used Tag is the first displayed. I've tried multiple things but it want sort by the result of count($rows).

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
<xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/News/Rows/Row[contains(normalize-space(@Tag), $Tag)]"/>                           
<xsl:variable name="RowsTag" select="/dsQueryResponse/News_-_Tags/Rows/Row"/>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)" />

<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
      <td valign="top">
          <div>
             <xsl:for-each select="$RowsTag[not(@Title = preceding-sibling::*/@Title)]">
               <xsl:sort select="count($Rows)" order="descending" />
               <xsl:variable name="SrcPos"><xsl:number /></xsl:variable>
               <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowviewTag">
                   <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows" />
                   <xsl:with-param name="Tag" select="$Tag" />
               </xsl:call-template>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </div> 
      </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

The result that i get is sorted alphabetical.

A (1)
C (6)
Z (2)

What i need is that it is displayed in this way...

C (6)
Z (2)
A (1)

Any suggestions how i can achieve it?

Comment: Post the input XML.

Comment: how can i get the XML input of a sharepoint list? sry i doesnt have much experience with sharepoint

Comment: If `Rows` are children of your element selected by `for-each` then omit the `$` and write `count(Rows)`  - the way you write it count($Rows) is constant and refers to the Rows variable declared in the third line

Comment: Try by changing <xsl:sort select="count($Rows)" order="descending" /> to <xsl:sort select="count($Rows)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>.

Comment: "*how can i get the XML input of a sharepoint list?*" By using a stylesheet with only the *identity transform* template?

Comment: "<xsl:sort select="count($Rows)" order="descending" data-type="number"/> doesnt work and without $ the same